# About to remove view, What is the difference the following two ways in android

Tags: java, android

I am very confused what the difference about the following two ways.

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.frame);
Stack<View> stack = new Stack<>();
MyView myView = new myView();
stack.push(myView)
frameLayout.addView(myView);

//the first way
MyView my = (MyView)stack.pop();
frameLayout.remove(my);

//the second way
View view = stack.pop();
frameLayout.remove(view);
```

What is the difference?

Comment: The first way has an unnecessary cast. That's all.

Comment: Why is unnecessary?And you mean that the result of two ways are the same，right?

Comment: The `FrameLayout` doesn't doesn't need to know (and doesn't really care) what specific _kind_ of `View` it is; just that it's a `View`. And, yes, both will have the same result.